# Software package for interfacing Arduino with MAX MSP?

Tags: arduino, maxmsp

What is a good software package for interfacing Arduino's input pins to MAX/MSP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SimpleMessageSystem is a library for the Arduino that allows you to send, receive and parse characters, integers and lists between Arduino and Max/Msp or Pure Data.

Source: http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/MaxMSP

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree SimpleMessageSystem looks like the easiest to impalement. However you can also pick up any serial communication that pops up in Arduino's serial monitor, by using the serial object that comes with MAX MSP.

```
{
"patcher" :     {
    "fileversion" : 1,
    "rect" : [ 54.0, 60.0, 602.0, 602.0 ],
    "bglocked" : 0,
    "defrect" : [ 54.0, 60.0, 602.0, 602.0 ],
    "openrect" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
    "openinpresentation" : 0,
    "default_fontsize" : 12.0,
    "default_fontface" : 0,
    "default_fontname" : "Arial",
    "gridonopen" : 0,
    "gridsize" : [ 15.0, 15.0 ],
    "gridsnaponopen" : 0,
    "toolbarvisible" : 1,
    "boxanimatetime" : 200,
    "imprint" : 0,
    "metadata" : [  ],
    "boxes" : [             {
            "box" :                 {
                "maxclass" : "preset",
                "id" : "obj-3",
                "patching_rect" : [ 244.0, 499.0, 16.0, 16.0 ],
                "numinlets" : 1,
                "numoutlets" : 4,
                "outlettype" : [ "preset", "int", "preset", "int" ],
                "preset_data" : [                         {
                        "number" : 1,
                        "data" : [ 5, "obj-11", "toggle", "int", 1, 5, "obj-6", "number", "int", 426, 5, "obj-1", "multislider", "list", 426, 6, "obj-24", "gain~", "list", 127, 10.0, 5, "obj-4", "filtergraph~", "nfilters", 1, 9, "obj-4", "filtergraph~", "setoptions", 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 8, "obj-4", "filtergraph~", "params", 0, 587.329529, 9.119135, 17.75762 ]
...
```

This MAX 5 patch will receive data from Arduino's serial monitor, I think it was used to connect a pot to one of the analogue inputs, that could then be used to control the cutoff frequency of a filter in MAX MSP.

Comment: Wow this forum really hates Max MSP code! It's all over the place.